# C#: Listbox: How to add data in addition to text for each item

Tags: c#, object, collections, listbox

Consider the following text as two lists(separated with ':'), as you can see the second rows are always unique but items in the first row can be repetitive;

```
Book:m234
Clover:h67
Pencil:a12
Book:x67
```

I want to populate a listbox with items in the first column(Book, Clover, ...) but the problem is that when I'm going to retrieve the selected item in the listbox, I can't be sure about it's respective value in second column. (for example in case of 'Book');

**NOTE:** I'm not looking for any workaround for solving this problem because there are many. What I want to know is that:

Is it possible to pass and object to `ListBox.Items.Add()` in a way that the object carries two values(each value/property for each column) and in time of getting the selected item, we would have an object with the two values(maybe as the properties of the object)?

Is such a thing possible in C#? (.NET 4.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass objects that pair data with names to your `ListBox`, and control what gets displayed and what gets returned back to you by using `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`:

```
class ListBoxItem {
    public string DisplayName {get;set;}
    public string Identifier {get;set;}
}
...
ListBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem {
    DisplayName = "Book", Identifier = "m234"
});
ListBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem {
    DisplayName = "Clover", Identifier = "h67"
});
ListBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem {
    DisplayName = "Pencil", Identifier = "a12"
});
ListBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem {
    DisplayName = "Book", Identifier = "x67"
});
ListBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
ListBox.ValueMember = "Identifier";
```

Now your list box displays the same list of strings, but the values returned for end-user selections would be different.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A question; suppose I want to show the 'Identifier' of the selected item in MessageBox.Show()
what code should I use for that?

Comment: @wiki Typically you would keep a little "map" for yourself - say, a `Dictionary<string,ListBoxItem> listBoxIdMap` with `Identifier` used as the key. This lets you pick `listBoxMap[selectedKey]` item, and display any part of it.